# Find string, then find string in-between chars

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time with this....

So, I have a load of text:

```
a:13:{s:9:"live_odds";i:0;s:14:"show_matchbook";i:0;s:12:"show_betfred";i:1;s:16:"show_williamhill";i:1;s:12:"betfair_show";i:1;s:16:"betfair_username";N;s:16:"betfair_password";s:9:"";s:20:"betfair_affiliate_id";s:3:"888";
```

Now, what I am trying to do is search for **betfair_affiliate_id";s:3:** within that bulk of text and then display the text between the speech marks.

I was trying

```
        $betfred_show = 'betfair_affiliate_id";s:3:"';
        $betfred_show_value = substr($string, strpos($string, $betfred_show) + strlen($betfred_show), 3);
```

which does work, it brings back **888**... but it's not really future proof as this just gets the 3 next digits. However, these could change to 4 or 5 digits.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ever heard of regex? http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: What is the source of your data?  It vaguely resembles JSON, but not quite.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is serialised data (native to PHP). In this case it is a serialised array

Comment: This looks like a php serialized array... Doesn't it make _much_ more sense to deserialize it and use the actual array elements instead of performing string operations on the serialized binary data?

Comment: If it's really just about extracting individual bits, then a regex might be an option. `~:"key";s:\d+"(\d+)~`, albeit less resilient to type variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a serialised array. You can simply [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)  it and access the key

```
$array = unserialize($input);
$output = $array['betfair_affiliate_id'];
```

Comment: Doesn't work https://3v4l.org/VN0jY

Comment: @Mohammad OP has given truncated input text.

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was trying to do.